# Using array of objects gives seemingly incorrect index out of bounds error in ContentView

Tags: swiftui

### Background

This is the first time I am writing a full app in SwiftUI or Swift at all for that matter. I’m using SwiftUI to try and build a simple choose-your-own-adventure app. It basically involves a Directed graph where each node may or may not have 'decisions' associated with it and can lead to one or more other nodes depending on the decision selected by the user. A node’s text is displayed on the screen and if it has decisions, their text is displayed as two buttons. Depending on what the user selects, another node’s text is displayed to the screen (if there is no decision it is supposed to automatically get the next node - haven’t figured that out but that is not the purpose of this question, I just use a placeholder button with no text that must be clicked to move on in the case of no decisions to be made).

#### Structure

Aside from the starting files: I have a `Node` class, `Decision` struct, and `Game` struct.

**Node**
An `ObservableObject` with three relevante properties: `String` for text, `Decision` array for the decisions, and `@Published Node` array for the children.

It also has a relevent function called `addChild(child: Node)` which adds a Node to the children array.

```
class Node: ObservableObject {
    let id: Double
    let text: String
    let decisions: [Decision]
    let speaker: Int
    @Published var children: [Node] = []

    init(id: Double, text: String, decisions: [Decision], speaker: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.decisions = decisions
        self.speaker = speaker
    }

    func addChild(child: Node) {
        print("Added a child")
        self.children.append(child)
    }


    func getChild(whichChild: Int) -> Node {
        return self.children[whichChild]
    }

    func hasDecisions() -> Bool {
        return (decisions.count > 0)
    }

    func hasChildren() -> Bool {
        return (children.count > 0)
    }
}
```

**Decision**
Has two relevant properties: `String` for text and `Int` the index of the child that it leads to. No methods.

**Game**
Has only one method called `createGame() -> Node` which creates the whole story tree by initializing `Node`s and `Decision`s and then adding them together using the `addChild(child: Node)` method. It returns the root node which is supposed to contain the entire story tree.

```
public struct Game {
    func createGame() -> Node {

        // First 13 Nodes for Testing
        var n1 = Node(id: 1, text: "Just a text node...", decisions: [], speaker: 0)

        let n2d1 = Decision(id: "n2d1", text: "Who is this?", whichChild: 0)
        let n2d2 = Decision(id: "n2d2", text: "Whoa. Is this an actual person?", whichChild: 0)
        let n2d = [n2d1, n2d2]
        var n2 = Node(id: 2, text: "Node with decisions...", decisions: n2d, speaker: 1)

        var n3 = Node(id: 3, text: "Both decisions lead to this node...", decisions: [], speaker: 1)


        n1.addChild(child: n2)
        n2.addChild(child: n3)

        return n1

    }

}
```

**ContentView**
The content view may be where my problems are coming from, here is the code for that:
it displays all the text that has been already played by the user and then depending what the user chooses to do next finds the next `Node` whose text and decisions should be displayed.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let root = Game().createGame()

    @ObservedObject private var currentNode = Game().createGame()
    @State private var previouslyPlayed: [String] = []
    @State private var decisionList: [Int] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //Loop through previously played, displaying each message
            ForEach(previouslyPlayed, id: \.self) { text in
                Text(text)
            }
            Text(currentNode.text)
            HStack {
                if (currentNode.decisions.count > 0) {
                    ForEach(currentNode.decisions, id: \.text) { decision in
                        Button(decision.text) {
                            self.makeDecision(decision: decision)
                            print(self.decisionList)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Button("Move on...") {
                        self.noDecision()
                        print(self.decisionList)
                    }
                    // self.noDecision()
                }

            }
        }
    }

    mutating func makeDecision(decision: Decision) {

        self.previouslyPlayed.append(self.currentNode.text)
        self.previouslyPlayed.append(decision.text)
        self.decisionList.append(decision.whichChild)
        // Get the next node using decisionList
        var nextNode = root
        for whichChild in self.decisionList {
            nextNode = nextNode.getChild(whichChild: whichChild)
        }

        self.currentNode = nextNode

        // self.previouslyPlayed.append(nextNode.text)

    }

    mutating func noDecision() {
        self.previouslyPlayed.append(self.currentNode.text)
        self.decisionList.append(0)

        var nextNode = root
        print(root.children[0].children)
        for whichChild in self.decisionList {
            print("Which child: \(whichChild)")
            print(nextNode.text)
            print(nextNode.children.count)
            nextNode = nextNode.getChild(whichChild: whichChild)
        }

        self.currentNode = nextNode
    }

}
```

### Problem

Originally, I had the `Node class` as a `struct`, and the `addChild` method was `mutating`. At that point I had an issue with, when playing the game, it would work fine for exactly one node-jump (as in when a user clicked button to make decision). But for the second node-jump, it would get index out of bounds errors and was unable to find the next node even though the graph was build correctly and the index should have existed.

I did some research and found some info on `ObservableObjects` and how array's of objects cause issues, so I made `Node` into a `class` and made the array of children `@Published` because it is the only variable that mutates the class data. Then I marked the two methods that are called when a user taps a button (makes a decision) to `mutating` since they would change the `@ObservableObject currentNode` property. Now however, the program won't even build because of the error `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable'`.

I have included all code I believe to be relevant above, but let me know if there is anything else you need to help. As always, thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is variant with fixes & some replicas, also some redesign made. Compiled & run with Xcode 11.4.

```
struct Decision {
    let id: String
    let text: String
    let whichChild: Int
}

class Node: ObservableObject {
    let id: Double
    let text: String
    let decisions: [Decision]
    let speaker: Int
    @Published var children: [Node] = []

    init(id: Double, text: String, decisions: [Decision], speaker: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.decisions = decisions
        self.speaker = speaker
    }

    func addChild(child: Node) {
        print("Added a child")
        self.children.append(child)
    }


    func getChild(whichChild: Int) -> Node {
        return self.children[whichChild]
    }

    func hasDecisions() -> Bool {
        return (decisions.count > 0)
    }

    func hasChildren() -> Bool {
        return (children.count > 0)
    }
}

public class Game: ObservableObject {
    let root = Game.createGame()
    @Published var currentNode = Game.createGame()

    static func createGame() -> Node {

        // First 13 Nodes for Testing
        var n1 = Node(id: 1, text: "Just a text node...", decisions: [], speaker: 0)

        let n2d1 = Decision(id: "n2d1", text: "Who is this?", whichChild: 0)
        let n2d2 = Decision(id: "n2d2", text: "Whoa. Is this an actual person?", whichChild: 0)
        let n2d = [n2d1, n2d2]
        var n2 = Node(id: 2, text: "Node with decisions...", decisions: n2d, speaker: 1)

        var n3 = Node(id: 3, text: "Both decisions lead to this node...", decisions: [], speaker: 1)


        n1.addChild(child: n2)
        n2.addChild(child: n3)

        return n1

    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var game = Game()

    @State private var previouslyPlayed: [String] = []
    @State private var decisionList: [Int] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //Loop through previously played, displaying each message
            ForEach(previouslyPlayed, id: \.self) { text in
                Text(text)
            }
            Text(game.currentNode.text)
            HStack {
                if (game.currentNode.decisions.count > 0) {
                    ForEach(game.currentNode.decisions, id: \.text) { decision in
                        Button(decision.text) {
                            self.makeDecision(decision: decision)
                            print(self.decisionList)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Button("Move on...") {
                        self.noDecision()
                        print(self.decisionList)
                    }
                    // self.noDecision()
                }

            }
        }
    }

    func makeDecision(decision: Decision) {

        self.previouslyPlayed.append(game.currentNode.text)
        self.previouslyPlayed.append(decision.text)
        self.decisionList.append(decision.whichChild)
        // Get the next node using decisionList
        var nextNode = game.root
        for whichChild in self.decisionList {
            nextNode = nextNode.getChild(whichChild: whichChild)
        }

        game.currentNode = nextNode

        // self.previouslyPlayed.append(nextNode.text)

    }

    func noDecision() {
        self.previouslyPlayed.append(game.currentNode.text)
        self.decisionList.append(0)

        var nextNode = game.root
        print(game.root.children[0].children)
        for whichChild in self.decisionList {
            print("Which child: \(whichChild)")
            print(nextNode.text)
            print(nextNode.children.count)
            nextNode = nextNode.getChild(whichChild: whichChild)
        }

        game.currentNode = nextNode
    }

}
```